# How to check a radiobutton when I click on gridview row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I have a gridview with some bound fields and one radiobutton column. When I click on any column(entire row) of the gridview, that particular radiobutton should be checked by using javascript. How can I implement this? I searched google, I am able to find code to check only one radio button in a gridview but not for my requirement.

Comment: provide the js fiddle

Comment: Bind event to row and get the radio button inside

Comment: A single radio button doesn't make sense, they are meant to be in groups. Use a checkbox, set it's *checked* property to true (or false for unchecked).

Comment: Here is JS fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/U86Fx/